# Getting a QSqlError("", "", "") but the data is inserted

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

I am programming a Stock Control Program in Qt but when im inserting data I receive an error of `QSqlError("", "", "")`. The problem is that the data is being inserted into the SQLITE database but I'm unsure of what error means.

The code that I'm using to insert data into the database is below:

```
query_Account.prepare("INSERT INTO Customer(Company_Name, City, Phone_Number, Street_Adress, County, BULSTAT, Company_Owner, Account_Since) "
                  "VALUES (:Company_Name, :City, :Phone_Number, :Street_Adress, :County, :BULSTAT, :Company_Owner, :Account_Since)");
query_Account.bindValue(":Company_Name", ui->lineEdit_Company_Name->text());
query_Account.bindValue(":City", ui->lineEdit_City->text());
query_Account.bindValue(":Phone_Number", (ui->lineEdit_Phone_Num->text()).toInt());
query_Account.bindValue(":Street_Adress", ui->lineEdit_Street_Add->text());
query_Account.bindValue(":County", ui->lineEdit_County->text());
query_Account.bindValue(":BULSTAT", (ui->lineEdit_BULSTAT->text()).toInt());
query_Account.bindValue(":Company_Owner", ui->lineEdit_Company_Owner->text());
query_Account.bindValue(":Account_Since", 1776-07-04);
query_Account.exec();
qDebug() << "SQL query_Account:" << query_Account.executedQuery();
qDebug() << "SQL ERROR:" << query_Account.lastError();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not in fact getting an error. You're just unconditionally printing out an error even if you didn't get one.

```
if (query_Account.exec()) {
  // got no error, proceed
  qDebug() << "Yay!";
} else {
  // got an error, deal with it
  qDebug() << query_Account.executedQuery();
  qDebug() << query_Account.lastError();
}
```